# Is there a matrix (numpy) equivalent to these recursive equations?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following recursive equations I want to implement in Python
(the background is financial markets):

[image]

This is easily done sequentially, using a loop:

```
def compute(x, y, χ, γ, a0, b0):
    a = [a0]
    b = [b0]

    α = [a[0]]
    β = [b[0]]

    for i in range(len(x)):
        a.append(-α[i]*x[i] + β[i]*y[i]*γ[i])
        b.append(-β[i]*y[i] + α[i]*x[i]*χ[i])

        α.append(α[-1] + a[-1])
        β.append(β[-1] + b[-1])
    return α, β
```

A small-arrays example:

```
x = np.array([0.6, 0.4, 0., 0., 0.9])
y = np.array([0., 0., 0.3, 0.9, 0.])

χ = np.arange(100., 105., 1.)
γ = 1. / (χ - 1.)

print(np.array(compute(x, y, χ, γ, 1., 0.)))
```

would produce

```
>>> [[ 1.          0.4         0.24        0.46621782  0.93661782  0.09366178]  
     [ 0.         60.         76.16       53.312       5.3312     92.99862812]]
```

is there a way to do it in NumPy (which I expect to significantly speed up the computation)?

In other words: to compute the whole a and b vectors without using a loop, just NumPy functions?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example with small arrays?

Comment: What are the outputs of the algorithm? Do you need the `a` and `b` sequences at the end?

Comment: I Included an example. Eventually I need `α` and `β`, having `a` and `b` would be sufficient to compute them.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear first: I have no idea how make this faster using numpy. So this is *not an answer to your question*.

But: you can achieve some speedup using `numba`:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

N = 1000000

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
gamma = np.random.rand(N)
chi = np.random.rand(N)

a = [.2]
b = [.3]
alpha = [a[0]]
beta = [b[0]]

def compute_in_python():
    for i in range(len(x)):
        a.append(-alpha[i]*x[i] + beta[i]*y[i]*gamma[i])
        b.append(-beta[i]*y[i] + alpha[i]*x[i]*chi[i])

        alpha.append(alpha[-1]+a[-1])
        beta.append(beta[-1]+b[-1])


@jit(nopython=True)
def compute_with_numba(x,y,gamma,chi,a0, b0, alpha0, beta0):
    N = len(x)
    a = np.empty(N+1)
    b = np.empty(N+1)
    alpha = np.empty(N+1)
    beta = np.empty(N+1)
    a[0] = a0
    b[0] = b0
    alpha[0] = alpha0
    beta[0] = beta0
    for i in range(N):
        a[i+1] = -alpha[i] * x[i] + beta[i] * y[i] * gamma[i]
        b[i+1] = -beta[i] * y[i] + alpha[i] * x[i] * chi[i]

        alpha[i+1] = alpha[i]+a[i+1]
        beta[i+1] = beta[i]+b[i+1]

    return a,b,alpha,beta
```

Vanilla python loops:

```py
In [23]: %time compute_in_python()
CPU times: user 1.6 s, sys: 24.8 ms, total: 1.63 s
Wall time: 1.63 s
```

Numba-jitted:

```py
In [42]: %time res = compute_with_numba(x,y,gamma,chi,a[0], b[0], alpha[0], beta[0])
CPU times: user 13 ms, sys: 3.36 ms, total: 16.4 ms
Wall time: 16.4 ms
```

Note that the first call to `compute_with_numba` will trigger the jit, so you should measure the runtime of the second call.

Again, this is not an answer to your question, but it still is approximately 100 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with matrix multiplication if you rearrange the elements to get  the following form

[image]

After that you can compute everything by simple matrix multiplications.

note that k, j, l, m of a 2x2 matrix are all available and the matrix they construct can be precomputed.

In this case they will be:

```
k = 1-x  
l = y*γ  
m = x*χ  
n = 1-y
```

Also I do recommend pre-allocating any array that might be used as the size is always available (appending a list is very costly).

In any case though a for loop is inevitable. But I guess the following would make it neat.

```py
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
def compute(mat, inp):
    return reduce(np.dot, mat) @ inp
```

Comment: this is interesting and pretty close to what I want! If I manage to figure out the solution from this I will update Yours and give it a tick

Comment: I got it! Though this is not exactly the solution that I was initially looking for (as it still contains a loop), it solves the problem as this technique allows **batching** (which makes it eligible even for GPU-parallelization). Thank You!

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you please give me a hint how to knit in the 'source terms' x, y, gamma, and chi into this matrix-power approach in order to achieve a time complexity of O(log N)? I think it must be some misunderstanding on my side, either regarding the question or your answer, but if even *reading* the array, x, ..., chi costs O(N), how can you compute a result that is a continuous function of every array element in O(log N)?

Comment: I totally agree that a matrix power A^N can be computed in O(log N), but your reformulation is rather a rearrangement to the form 'A_{N-1} * ... * A_1 * A_0 * [alpha0, beta0]^T', as I understand it. Despite not understanding how this product of N different matrices that each depend on arbitrary input can be computed in sub-linear time, I would be interested, how this matrix-product can be encoded in `numpy` so that is vectorizes well, avoiding an N-iteration python loop.

Comment: If anybody knows how to vectorize this recursive matrix product, I'm surely still interested too. As for the complexity, despite the practical usability of the solution, I also don't know how the O(NlogN) was inferred.

Comment: @philvec : D.ACAR's claim was that the matrix-power/matrix-product approach leads to a time complexity of O(log N), not O(N log N). O(N log N) wouldnt be of any benefit, as the original python-only solution you suggested in your question already had O(N), even though being all vanilla python loops and data structures. Regarding the 'practical usability': Is there any practical usability of this solution concerning a numpy-implmentation if no-one knows how to vectorize the resulting matrix-product in numpy?

Comment: Of course, my mistake, surely he said O(logN) - as I said, hard for me to guess why :P
The practical usability is, again as I said, that the operations can now be batched... wait... okay You are right :( I guess I got a little too excited by this idea. Marking as unsolved again...

Comment: Oh I see my mistake, it is in O(N) as the powers can not be skipped.

Comment: even if I made a mistake for the complexity it still would be faster than the vanilla solution.

Comment: well still even if it is in O(N) it would be faster than the vanilla form as the matrix matrix multiplications can be done in parallel and dgemm use more bandwidth (would give a slightly better speed up though as they are 2 by 2 matrices) also using numba it is trivial to specify the type of the matrix and gain more speed up there. So the easy approach would to pre-compute the matrices which is basically filling a 3D array by  the inputs, sending that to the function and do matrix multiplications in a for loop.

Comment: Regarding the question if a chained dot-product of N 2x2-matrices can be vectorized in numpy in order avoid a python-level loop with N-1 iterations: Probably not. [numpy.linalg.multi_dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html) does, semantically, exactly what we want, but the iteration is implemented in python there, it is not able to operate on one (N, 2, 2)-shaped array at C-level.

Comment: @D.ACAR I agree that taking your matrix-product approach and implementing the actual matrix computation in numba is probably among the fastest solutions we can achieve here without hacking C, given that it allows for parallelization. Yet, the question how 'to compute the whole a and b vectors without using a loop, just NumPy functions' remains open...

Comment: well the problem is that if we want to store all the intermediate results or not. if we have to store them a for loop is inevitable. If not I guess numpy.prod does what we want and is not a pure python method.

Comment: no, that won't work, np.prod is element-wise multiplication

Comment: You are right though np.linalg.multi_dot does it but its a recursive method. Again in any case you need a for loop. But with matrix multiplication and numba you get some degree of speed up

Comment: sorry for all the mistakes. hope my new answer would be helpful.